# How to Join two .csv files using Batch Scripting

Tags: windows-10, batch

I am a database developer, new to batch scripting. I have implemented the below solution in the Oracle database, but due to some constraints, I need to join the files directly.

I have two files( AM6973_20201011.csv and NIKE_22102019.csv), NIKE_22102019.csv file has some 10 columns, I want to add column 4, column6 and columns 13,15 and 18 from AM6973_20201011.csv to the NIKE_22102019.csv file. Both have a NikeKey as unique values.

My question is how can we join two .csv files in Batch scripting because I want to add columns from AM6973_20201011.csv to NIKE_22102019.csv only if the NikeKey is matching between both these files

[Please see the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD3ny.jpg)

I have attached some sample data for your reference

Comment: Batch is very much suitable for this requirement, I was able to do it in batch scripting took some time though, thanks for introducing the "Python", I never knew it existed before your post

Comment: Regarding Python, your welcome. And it's good to hear you resolved your issue. =) Since you have found a suitable solution in batch, please consider posting a detailed version of that solution as an answer to your question. It might help others going forward.